# How to install elasticsearch 7 and elasticsearch 6 in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two projects one project requires ElasticSearch 7 and another requires ElasticSearch 6. Is there any way I can install both of these versions? That would be fine if I need to stop one version before starting another version.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit too late, but probably someone was looking for the same issue :)

Please note that below is my own config and you need to adjust it for your system\folders\etc.

---

Download and unpack the repo (you can google for the actual latest release versions):

```
cd ~
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.8.23.tar.gz
tar -zxf elasticsearch-6.8.23.tar.gz
```

If you run ES 7 already, make sure you have stopped it (!) and edited configs and set up different cluster\node names.

For example, edit ES 7 as the main node\cluser:

```
sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

I added this config at the very bottom:

```
cluster.name: elastic_cluster1
node.name: node-1
node.master: true
node.data: true
transport.host: localhost
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

After that edit config for ES 6:

```
nano ~/elasticsearch-6.8.23/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

And put that at the very bottom:

```
cluster.name: elastic_cluster2
node.name: node-2
#node.master: true
node.data: true
transport.host: localhost
transport.tcp.port: 9304
http.port: 9204
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Now you just need to run ES 6 as a standalone version\process:

```
~/elasticsearch-6.8.23/bin/elasticsearch -d > /var/log/elasticsearch6.log &
```

So far all should be done. ES 7 and ES 6 are set up on different clusters and ports.

Use `9200` for v7 and `9204` for v6.